# Nextcloud docker install with SSH access enabled

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nextcloud

I’m trying to install SSH (and enable the service) on top of my Nextcloud installation in Docker, and have it work on reboot. Having run through many Dockerfile, docker-compose combinations I can’t seem to get this to work. Ive tried using entrypoint.sh scripts with Dockerfile, but it wants a CMD at the end and then it doesn’t execute the “normal” nextcloud start up.

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Start the ssh server
service ssh start

# Execute the CMD
exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nextcloud:latest

RUN apt update -y && apt-get install ssh -y
RUN apt-get install python3 -y && apt-get install sudo -y
RUN echo 'ansible ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
RUN useradd -m ansible -s /bin/bash
RUN sudo -u ansible mkdir /home/ansible/.ssh
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general I'd say - break the problem you're having down into smaller parts - it'll help isolate the source of the problem.

Here's how I'd approach the reported issue.

First - replace (in your Dockerfile)

```
apt-get install -y ssh
```

with the recommended

```
apt install -y openssh-server
```

Then - test just the required parts of your Dockerfile addressing the issue - simplify it just to the following:

```
FROM nextcloud:latest

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y openssh-server
```

Then build a test image using this Dockerfile via the command

```
docker build . -t test_nextcloud
```

This will build the image - giving it the name (tag) of `test_nextcloud`.

Then run a container from this newly built image via the docker run command

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -d --name nextcloud test_nextcloud
```

This will run the container on port `8080` in detatched mode, and  give the assicated container the name of `nextcloud`.

Then - with the container running - you should be able to enter into it using the following command

```
docker container exec -u 0 -it nextcloud bash
```

as root.

Now that you are in, you should be able to startup the ssh server via the command

```
service ssh start
```

Having followed a set of steps like this to confirm that you can indeed startup an ssh server in the nextcloud container, begin adding back in your additional logic (begining with the original Dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Getting SSH installed isn't the problem, it's making it run when the container starts, then letting the Nextcloud image start up do it's own thing afterwards.